# Ubuntu is stuck to update error while updating system

Tags: ubuntu

Every time I tried to run the following command on ubuntu terminal

**sudo apt update**

I get following error message in terminal

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Could any one explain more about this problem. Specifically what is the problem! and if there is any solutions for the same problem ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/948238/while-updating-the-ubuntu-16-04-does-not-have-a-release-file-error

Answer (score 0):

**In order to get rid of error , refer below link:**

[ubuntu-16-04-sudo-apt-get-update-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769925/ubuntu-16-04-sudo-apt-get-update-error)